# How to pick an image from gallery and store into SqLite database

Tags: java, android, image, sqlite, android-studio

I want to pick an image from phone gallery and store it in SqLite database. I have code where I am storing into database name, email, addres etc, but I do not know how to pick an Image from phone gallery and store an that Image into SqLite database. I will be thankful if you help me just with that, the rest for placing the Image into ListView I think I know how to do that.. Thanks
Here is my code for my DatabaseHelper:

```
package com.example.zadacaeden;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "kompanii_table";

public static final String COL_1 = "id";
public static final String COL_2 = "name";
public static final String COL_3 = "address";
public static final String COL_4 = "phone";
public static final String COL_5 = "website";
public static final String COL_6 = "email";
public static final String COL_7 = "latitude";
public static final String COL_8 = "longitude";
public static final String COL_9 = "kategorija";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, address VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR," +
            " website VARCHAR, email VARCHAR, latitude VARCHAR, longitude VARCHAR, kategorija VARCHAR )" );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

// ZA DA SE VNESE DATATA
public boolean insertData(String name, String address, String phone, String website, String email, String latitude, String longitude, String kategorija){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, address);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, phone);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, website);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, email);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, latitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, longitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_9, kategorija);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}



// ZA DA SE PRINTA DATATA OD BAZATA U LISTI - SERVICES
public ArrayList<Item> getDataServices(){
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //SELECT columnName FROM yourTable WHERE CONTAINS (columnName, ‘yourSubstring’);
    String query = "select * from "+TABLE_NAME +" where "+ COL_9 +" like '%Servis%'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String  ime = cursor.getString(1);
        String adresa = cursor.getString(2);
        String telefon = cursor.getString(3);
        String websajt = cursor.getString(4);
        Item item = new Item(ime, adresa, telefon, websajt);
        arrayList.add(item);
    }
    return arrayList;
}
// ZA DA SE PRINTA DATATA OD BAZATA U LISTI - FUN
public ArrayList<Item> getDataFun(){
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //SELECT columnName FROM yourTable WHERE CONTAINS (columnName, ‘yourSubstring’);
    String query = "select * from "+TABLE_NAME +" where "+ COL_9 +" like '%Zabava%'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String  ime = cursor.getString(1);
        String adresa = cursor.getString(2);
        String telefon = cursor.getString(3);
        String websajt = cursor.getString(4);
        Item item = new Item(ime, adresa, telefon, websajt);
        arrayList.add(item);
    }
    return arrayList;
}

// ZA DA SE PRINTA DATATA OD BAZATA U LISTI - INDUSTRY
public ArrayList<Item> getDataIndustry(){
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //SELECT columnName FROM yourTable WHERE CONTAINS (columnName, ‘yourSubstring’);
    String query = "select * from "+TABLE_NAME +" where "+ COL_9 +" like '%Industrija%'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String  ime = cursor.getString(1);
        String adresa = cursor.getString(2);
        String telefon = cursor.getString(3);
        String websajt = cursor.getString(4);
        Item item = new Item(ime, adresa, telefon, websajt);
        arrayList.add(item);
    }
    return arrayList;
}

// ZA DA SE PRINTA DATATA OD BAZATA U LISTI - EDUCATION
public ArrayList<Item> getDataEducation(){
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //SELECT columnName FROM yourTable WHERE CONTAINS (columnName, ‘yourSubstring’);
    String query = "select * from "+TABLE_NAME +" where "+ COL_9 +" like '%Edukacija%'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String  ime = cursor.getString(1);
        String adresa = cursor.getString(2);
        String telefon = cursor.getString(3);
        String websajt = cursor.getString(4);
        Item item = new Item(ime, adresa, telefon, websajt);
        arrayList.add(item);
    }
    return arrayList;
}}
```

Here is my Activity Class where I am entering the values of everything what is stored into DB:

```
 package com.example.zadacaeden;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Vnesuvanje extends AppCompatActivity {


// ZA CHECKBOX
ArrayList<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>();
public String final_checkB_selection = "";

// ZA BAZA
CheckBox servis;
CheckBox zabava;
CheckBox industrija;
CheckBox edukacija;

///////////
ListView ll;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
Button buttonSave;
EditText editIme, editAdresa, editTelefon, editWebsajt, editEmail, editLatitude, editLongitude;

// Za image
Button btnChooseImage;
private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vnesuvanje);

    //ActionBar menu
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);

    // CheckBoxs
    servis = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Services);
    zabava = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Fun);
    industrija = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Industry);
    edukacija = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Education);

    // Edit Texts
    editIme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ime);
    editAdresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Adresa);
    editTelefon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Telefon);
    editWebsajt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.WebSite);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    editLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Latitude);
    editLongitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Longitude);

    // Button
    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    // ListView / DataBase / ArrayList
    ll = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    AddData();

}

// ZA DA SE DODADE DATATA VO TABELA
public void AddData(){
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    boolean isInserted = databaseHelper.insertData(
                            editIme.getText().toString(),
                            editAdresa.getText().toString(),
                            editTelefon.getText().toString(),
                            editWebsajt.getText().toString(),
                            editEmail.getText().toString(),
                            editLatitude.getText().toString(),
                            editLongitude.getText().toString(),
                            final_checkB_selection
                            );

                    if(isInserted == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(Vnesuvanje.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(Vnesuvanje.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}

// CHECKBOX TEST
public void selectItem(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Services:
            if(checked)
            {
                selection.add("Servis");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            else if(!checked)
            {
                selection.remove("Servis");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Fun:
            if(checked)
            {
                selection.add("Zabava");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            else if(!checked)
            {
                selection.remove("Zabava");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Industry:
            if(checked)
            {
                selection.add("Industrija");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            else if(!checked)
            {
                selection.remove("Industrija");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Education:
            if(checked)
            {
                selection.add("Edukacija");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            else if(!checked)
            {
                selection.remove("Edukacija");
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            break;
    }
        final_checkB_selection = selection.toString();
}}
```

And in this Activity I am placing into listView the data from Database:

```
package com.example.zadacaeden;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class ServicesScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
// implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

// x i y za swipe/slide - left/right
float x1, x2, y1, y2;
//za click na slikite imagebutton
private ImageButton button;

//Za print od baza u ListView
ListView ll;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
public static ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
MyAdapter myAdapter;



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_services_screen);

    //ActionBar menu
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    //Image button services on click
    button = findViewById(R.id.ServicesImageBtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openServicesScreen();
        }
    });
    //Image button fun on click
    button = findViewById(R.id.FunImageBtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openFunScreen();
        }
    });
    //Image button industry on click
    button = findViewById(R.id.IndustryImageBtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openIndustryScreen();
        }
    });
    //Image button education on click
    button = findViewById(R.id.EducationImageBtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openEducationScreen();
        }
    });

    //ListView
    ll = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    loadDataInListView();

    // SEARCH
    search();

    //
    /////////////////////////START SWIPE LEFT-RIGHT ON LISTVIEW/////////////
    SwipeListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeListViewTouchListener(
                    ll,
                    new SwipeListViewTouchListener.OnSwipeCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(ServicesScreen.this, FunScreen.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(ServicesScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    },
                    true, // example : left action = dismiss
                    false); // example : right action without dismiss animation
    ll.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    /////////////////////////////////END SWIPE LEFT-RIGHT ON LISTVIEW///////////////////////////////////////////////
}



//SEARCH  VO LISTI////////////////
public void search(){
    EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
    theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            (ServicesScreen.this).myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}
// END SEARCH  VO LISTI////////////////

/////////ZA VNESUVANJE SCREEN KLIK/////////////////////////////
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.item1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Vnesuvanje.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

/////////END ZA VNESUVANJE SCREEN KLIK/////////////////////////////

```
// DATABAZA da gi printa vo listView
public void loadDataInListView(){
    arrayList = databaseHelper.getDataServices();
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
    ll.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



//ImageButton Open ServicesScreen function
public void openServicesScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServicesScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//ImageButton Open FunScreen function
public void openFunScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FunScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//ImageButton Open IndustryScreen function
public void openIndustryScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IndustryScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//ImageButton Open EducationScreen function
public void openEducationScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EducationScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//Swipe left - right
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent){
    switch (touchEvent.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = touchEvent.getX();
            y1 = touchEvent.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = touchEvent.getX();
            y2 = touchEvent.getY();
            if(x1 > x2){
                Intent i = new Intent(ServicesScreen.this, FunScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if(x1 < x2){
                Intent i = new Intent(ServicesScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

//END Swipe left - right
}
```

Comment: You need to load the image as a series of bytes (ByteBuffer will be useful) and then add a field to your SQLite database of type BLOB. You can then store those bytes in the BLOB field.

Comment: You could store the bitmap data into the database or you could instead create a file and store the URI to that file instead. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use BLOB from SQLite for your purposes.

Also you have to add a new field to your data class with type of byte[] (ByteArray in Kotlin)

Use this code for converting your drawable to byte[]:

```
Drawable d;
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

And this code to convert byte[] to drawable when you want to retreive data from DB:

```
BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.size))
```

Where blob - your byte[] from DB

Hope this helps